# Source Control Exporer history showing no changes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

The history of changes for an item is empty in Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 (or 2015). The message *No history entries were found for the specified item. Is there a way to debug this?

[image]

It works if I specify the source location $TP/File.h in the source control explorer.

It works from the web interface  http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TP/_versionControl?path=%24%2FTP%2FFile.h&_a=history

It works from the command line:

```
>tf history "$/TP/File.h" /recursive /noprompt /format:detailed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changeset: 996201
User: ...
Date: 17 September 2014 10:58:06

Comment:
  TFS406125 ....

Items:
  edit $/TP/File.h

Check-in Notes:
  Code Reviewer:
  Performance Reviewer:
  Security Reviewer:

Policy Warnings:
  Override Reason:
    .
  Messages:
    Internal error in Custom Path Policy. Error loading the Custom Path Policy p
olicy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.
CustomPathPolicy, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5
0a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions: Please contact your admini
strator
    Internal error in Custom Path Policy. Error loading the Custom Path Policy p
olicy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.
CustomPathPolicy, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5
0a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions: Please contact your admini
strator

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changeset: 876081
User: ..
Date: 27 January 2014 11:33:23

Comment:
  Project renamed and solution cleaned up.

Items:
  rename, edit $/TP/File.h

Check-in Notes:
  Code Reviewer:
  Performance Reviewer:
  Security Reviewer:
```

Versions:

Team Foundation Server 2015

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2013 - Update 1   06191-004-0456024-02093
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2013 - Update 1

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06191-004-0456024-02093
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools   12.0
Power Tools that extend the Team Foundation Server integration with Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you add if you are connecting to VSTS or TFS (what version and update). Please also add what update your VS 2013 and 2015 are on.

Comment: If you specify the server path $/TP/File.h in the Source location, are you able to get the history? Can you reproduce this issue on another client machine?

Comment: I've also tested in Team Explorer 2013 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776) instead of VS, but still can't reproduce your issue. Did you also test in Team Explorer?

Comment: I installed Team Explorer 2013. Is that the same as the plug-in for VS 2013 or a standalone app?

Comment: I contacted support inside of my company and they are also trying to reproduce it on another machine.

Comment: @Damian There is a standalone Team Explorer 2013, you may download it from the website as I mentioned above, to see whether it works.

Comment: I downloaded and it TE2013 but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem:

In Workspace the working folder where mapped once on the top level and then again further down the directory tree. 
After I removing the mapping further down the directory tree it worked.

For example:
[image]